# 304 Not Modified IN linked In API Integration

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

am trying to change role from administer to DIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER but am getting 304 not modified response

https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationAcls/(organization:urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXXXXXX,role:DIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER,roleAssignee:urn%3Ali%3Aperson%3XXXXXXXXX)

{
"state":"REQUESTED",
"role":"DIRECT_SPONSORED_CONTENT_POSTER",
"roleAssignee":"urn:li:person:XXXXXXXXXXX",
"organization":"urn:li:organization:XXXXXXXXX"
}

i read the documentation [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-access-control-by-role?view=li-lms-2022-10&tabs=http#request-direct-sponsored-content-poster-role) followed the same step but am receiving 304 status

```
  response: {
      status: 304,
      statusText: 'Not Modified',
      headers: [Object],
      config: [Object],
      request: [ClientRequest],
      data: ''
    }
```

Comment: `304` is a redirect code, it shouldn't indicate if the operation succeeds. Does the role changes after this?

Comment: no, in doc response is 203 for success

Comment: It's only working with me with version 202304 or older.